# Retrieve a table from mysql dump sql file using Java Runtime

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I can successfully retrieve a table from MySql Dump sql file using terminal command sed but it is not working with Java Runtime.

I could successfully retrieve mytable from mydump.sql using following terminal command

```
 >sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`cusprod`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' mydump.sql > 
 >mytable.sql
```

But the problem is I am not able to use this in my Java program. Find below codes.

```
 String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"sed", "-n", "-e", "'/DROP 
 TABLE.*``mytable``/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p'", "/home/mydump.sql > 
 /home/mytable.sql"};  
 >Process runtimeProcess;  
 >runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
```

I expect to get mytable.sql file. At present I am getting from terminal command but with Java Runtime I am getting error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
Could not retrieve Table from Selected backup
```

Comment: Remove the `'` from the sed arguments. And un-duplicate the ` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike typing command from a terminal, `Runtime.exec` (and all other languages) handles all parameters you passed to it as raw values and pass them directly to `sed` command.
So, when you pass ``` "'/DROP TABLE.*``mytable``/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p'" ``` in the array, you are passing

```
'/DROP TABLE.*``mytable``/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p'
```

as script to `sed`, instead of

```
/DROP TABLE.*``mytable``/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p
```

Note that there is no quotes mark in the script.

You do not need to quote your script in Java --- the string itself will represents the whole script directly.

There is also a similar issue in your last argument. You can't use `>` to redirect your output when you use `Runtime.exec`. 
You should write your own code to read and redirect output from `sed` `Process` to your desired file.

Try the following:

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sed", "-e", "/DROP TABLE.*`cusprod`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p", "/home/mydump.sql"});
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/mytable.sql")) {
  IOUtils.copy(process.getInputStream(), outputStream);
  process.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
  // Error handling
}
```

This will run command:

```sh
sed -e '/DROP TABLE.*`cusprod`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' '/home/mydump.sql'
```

and write output to file `/home/mytable.sql`.

[IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is an utility class from Apache.

Comment: Thanks. It looks IOUtils seems to be [Deprecated] If you could given me link to get it or some alternative.

Comment: I tried with following code but output file is again full dump and not mytable as desired. try (InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream())
{
    Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get("mytable.sql"));
  process.waitFor();

Comment: @ICL Sales EXIMON `You can't use > to redirect your output when you use Runtime.exec. `, that leads to the question, why doing this with `Runtime` anyway, and not with native Java IO and pattern matching.